# Handlebars: JSON object can't be printed

Tags: json, handlebars.js

I try to print out the key `category` with value `Animal` but nothing gets printed out. If I do `Console.log(row.category);` it gets printed out as expected.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var row = {
    "category" : "Animal"
};
</script>
Output: {{ row.category }}
```

It must be a very stupid basic mistake but I can't figure it out with Javascript and Handlebars tutorials/docs.

Comment: That's not a JSON object, it's a JavaScript object. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: If I do `$.parseJSON(row.toString())` I get SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: Yes, you would. Because that's not going to give you JSON (it'll give you the string `[object Object]`, which is not valid JSON). You don't have, or need, JSON for what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't normally include the name of your *variable* referring to the object (`row`), just the object's contents, e.g. `{{ category }}`.

You'd either do that in a string that you compiled into a function via `Handlebars.compile`, and then used on the object, like so:

```js
var row = {
    "category" : "Animal"
};
var template = Handlebars.compile("Category: {{ category }}");
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
  "beforeend",
  template(row)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.2/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```

...or you'd do it with template elements in the HTML (so you could keep markup and code separate):

```js
var row = {
  "category": "Animal"
};
var template = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById("entry-template").innerHTML);
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
  "beforeend", template(row)
);
```

```html
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  Category: {{category}}
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.2/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```

In both cases, you end up with a string that you have to put somewhere on the page. In the examples above I've used `document.body.insertAdjacentHTML`, but it would be more typical to have container elements or similar you looked up with `getElementById` or `querySelector` and then filled in.